# GIT : invalid path '.editorconfig'

Tags: git, github, editorconfig

Getting following error while cloning the project from master:

error: invalid path '.editorconfig '
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

Below is the config in my .editorconfig file

```
# editorconfig
root = true
[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
3
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

Answer (score 3):

> '.editorconfig '

The filename has a trailing space and it seems you're on a graphical environment that doesn't allow such filenames.

The only way to fix it is to clone the repository on a Unix/Linux OS (try WSL2, docker, virtual machine), fix the filename and commit.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is another way of fixing this. I had the same problem with the trailing whitespace and the suggestion below helped me.

The reason why you get the error is that Windows doesn’t support trailing space characters and automatically removes them when saving a file. On the other hand, Linux does support both leading and trailing whitespaces in filenames.

Git knows about these limitations and has a special config setting to control it:

core.protectNTFS

If set to true, do not allow checkout of paths that would cause problems with the NTFS filesystem, e.g. conflict. with 8.3 “short” names. Defaults to true on Windows, and false elsewhere.

The reason why other people can clone the repo without issues is that core.protectNTFS is set to false (manually or because of underlying OS)

So, to clone the repo on Windows you can use the following command:

```
git clone -c core.protectNTFS=false <repo url>
```